# Problems with MediaWiki's AccessControl extension

Tags: mediawiki, acl, access-control

I've installed the [AccessControl](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AccessControl) MediaWiki extension however it seems like it causes an access denied error if you search for anything even contained within the page that is access controlled.

Anyone using this extension?

All I want to do is hide one page in the wiki from everyone except for 5 people.

MediaWiki version 1.18.0
AccessControl version 2.1

Comment: On the documentation page for the extension it looks like the search thing is working as designed. Have you tried any of the other [access control extensions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Page_specific_user_rights_extensions)?

Comment: I solved it by adding another namespace to put the pages I need to secure in. I then removed the namespace from being searchable by implementing the searchablenamespaces hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding another namespace to put the pages I need to secure in. I then removed the namespace from being searchable by implementing the searchablenamespaces hook.

By doing this, there will never be an access denied page displayed just by searching for  text that happens to be in an access controlled page.

Here is the code for $IP/extensions/NoSearchNameSpace/NoSearchNameSpace.php

```
<?php
// This is a quick hack to remove certain listed namespaces from being searchable
// Just set a list of namespace IDs in the wgNoSearchNamespaces array in LocalSettings
// ie $wgNoSearchNamespaces = array(500,501) would remove 500 and 501 from being searched
$wgHooks['SearchableNamespaces'][] = 'noSearchNameSpace';
function noSearchNameSpace($arr){
    global $wgNoSearchNamespaces;
    foreach($wgNoSearchNamespaces as $ns){
        unset($arr[$ns]);
    }

    return $arr;
}
```

Example LocalSettings.php entry:

```
// Add two custom namespaces. One for ACL pages.
// one for pages that will be ACL'd that should not be searched.
$wgExtraNamespaces[500] = "ACL";
$wgExtraNamespaces[501] = "NoSearch";


// Include the NoSearchNamespace extension
require_once("extensions/NoSearchNamespace/NoSearchNameSpace.php");
$wgNoSearchNamespaces = array('500','501');
```

Comment: You can mark your own answer as the correct answer. Good job tracking this down.

Comment: In case anyone is looking for the actual code I wrote to remove a namespace from being searchable, I added it above

Answer (score 1):

I tried it with 1.20.2, and had the problem when a page I was searching for contained text being searched, putting it in the list of search results, which provoked an error because the "hookUserCan" function in AccessControl.php didn't return a value. To try to fix this, I modified line 341 of  AccessControl.php ("return doRedirect( 'accesscontrol-info-anonymous' );" to "return false;". This forces the search results to return just the title of the page, and then gets a permission error if an unauthorized user tries to open it. This is not a perfect fix, but it is sufficient for my purposes.

Editted, this is a better answer:

I made some modifications to the AccessControl.php program, and now it appears to work ok with MediaWiki user groups. A remaining problem is that the TITLES of protected pages show in the search results. This is fixable in the main MediaWiki source code (SpecialSearch.php, around line 562), but according to comments in that code, it would screw up the paging.

Here is my git directory, which can be unzipped to $IP/extensions/AccessControl:

https://ejc.s3.amazonaws.com/AccessControlGit.zip

Here is just the AccessControl.php file: http://pastebin.com/WnyB6gBw

Note that this has only been tested (briefly) with MediaWiki 1.20.2. I'm hoping that the author of the extension will review what I did and fix whatever problems remain.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by adding

```
return false;
```

after ALL LINES that say

```
doRedirect( 'accesscontrol-info-anonymous' );
```

Comment: Please don't hack the code, it makes upgrade painful and will eventually kill your wiki because you'll hate it. Guaranteed.